# Phrase meaning of equal parts

Tags: british-english, contemporary-english, literary-english

> IN THE CUT-THROAT realm of reality TV, “Wanted Down Under” is a survivor. A daytime fixture that has just finished its 13th season, the BBC documentary follows Britons contemplating relocating to Australia or New Zealand. **Equal parts travel, property and life-makeover programme,** it has a rival, “A New Life in Oz”, on Channel 5.

So the part from "equal" and onward gets unclear here since I can't think of a reasonable explanation to that equal part things. How often is "equal parts" used in such manner, how do I better make that out?

Comment: The phrasing in the original seems straightforward. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: It may seem straightforward to a native speaker. Not to me. Like my friend explained to me earlier that it means consist, a drama consists of three topics. But without any explanation, I could never come anywhere near this meaning. So if it is straight forward to you, can you offer me some other examples. When I searched on Google, it was all about math. Thank

Comment: Each Stack Exchange community defines its primary audience in its [tour]. Those for [english.se] would likely find the original straightforward, while some in the [ell.se] might need more help. Nevertheless, we welcome you and your questions here. The more basic a question, though, the more you need to explain what exactly you don’t understand. This is so that the community can then address the specific problem.

Comment: As to your question, “equal parts X, Y and Z” is a fairly well-known formula. As Kate’s answer notes, it means you have X, Y and Z, and you have about the same amount of each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the programme consists of travel documentary, property (house hunting) and 'life-makeover' (advice on starting a new life) in about equal proportions.